# Is it possible to reset a Timer in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-clock

first time poster here, so I hope you guys can help me :)

I'm working on a project in which I want to play a game of SET. It all works (JEEJ), however I want to be able to use some sort of time function. This will do the following:

```
at start of game the time starts running

if x:
        y
        reset timer to zero
elif not x and time == 30:
        do some action
```

I tried a lot of things; using time.time(), but this cannot be reset as far as I know; I found a few stopwatch like classes which I tried using, but they were slow (?); I tried perf_counter()... But now I'm at loss, so I hope any of you may know what to do...
Note that I want to "play" the game and do actions while the time runs...
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to clear a timer set with `pygame.time.set_timer()` right?

Comment: @mousetail, I have never heard of that function, so will look into that first. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. One is using time:

```
import time
timer_start = time.time()

if x:
    y 
    timer_start = time.time()
if not x and time.time() >= timer_start + 30:
    do some action
```

Note that I use >= because the time is highly unlikely to be exactly 30.0, better to fire it the first time after.

Another way is to use `pygame.time.set_timer()`:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 30000) #milliseconds
# You cal also use USEREVENT+1, USEREVENT+2 etc. if you want multiple timers

if x:
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 30000) #milliseconds

for event in pygame.event.get(): #merge this with your actual event loop
    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        if not x:
            y
        # reset the timer since it repeats by default
        pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the first option and it worked perfectely! :)